# First match of several regular expressions

Tags: elisp

I'm interested in finding the next-nearest match of two (or more) regular expressions.  (If more than one matches, the nearest should win.)  The regular expressions are too complicated to combine using "|".  My current approach is to write a loop that looks at "match-beginning", but is there a simpler, more standard way to handle this case?

Here's an example.  I want to match either:

```
"^sub\\s-+\\(\\(MEAT_EATING_\\)?ANIMAL[_A-Za-z0-9]*\\)\\b"
```

or:

```
"^\s*animal\s+\"\\([^\"]+\\)\""
```

whichever comes first.  Even if there is a way to combine those into a single regexp that still works, I'm not sure I want to.

(I now have a working implementation based on matching against both and selecting the one where (match-beginning 0) is least.)

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with `\\|`?
If you copy the next lines into the `*scratch*`-buffer, put the cursor where it is indicated and press <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-e</kbd> point will move behind `"string in quotes"` and you also get `"string in quotes"` as captured group 1 in the message buffer (Note, that I inserted `?1:` to set group 1 within the second regexp.

```lisp
(progn
  (re-search-forward
   (mapconcat 'identity
          '("^sub\\s-+\\(\\(MEAT_EATING_\\)?ANIMAL[_A-Za-z0-9]*\\)\\b"
        "^\s*animal\s+\"\\(?1:[^\"]+\\)\"")
          "\\|")
   nil t)
  (match-string-no-properties 1)) ;<< place cursor here before ';' and press C-x C-e

 animal "string in quotes"
next line
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, I guess - I definitely prefer the use of "mapconcat" over one big string literal with a "|" in the middle.

Comment: Often one searches for a regexp multiple times. Then it is better to `let` a variable, say `re`, to the result of `mapconcat` and use `(re-search-forward re nil t)`. Sometimes it is useful to define the list globally as the value of a user variable, say `my-list`. In this case it would look like `(let ((re (mapconcat 'identity my-list "\\|"))) ...)`.